# Duplicate div on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Basically, I want to be able to click the div with the class **click-to-add** and then I want that to add another div with the class **duplicate** above the **click-to-add** div and directly after the first **duplicate** div.

```
<div class="site-table-row header">
   <div class="site-table-row duplicate">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-table-row">
      <div class="click-to-add">Click Me</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance/direction!

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('button').click(function (){
        $('.header').append($('.header').html())
    
      /* console.log($('.header').html()); */
    })
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-table-row header">
   <div class="site-table-row duplicate">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-table-row">
      <button class="click-to-add">Click Me</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `clone` is the best way to do so :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved with

```
$('.click-to-add').click(function () {
   $('.duplicate').clone().insertAfter('.duplicate').last();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it with pure js but I think it can help you at least with the concept:

```
  <div class="site-table-row header">
   <div id="duplicatediv" class="site-table-row duplicate">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-table-row">
      <div class="click-to-add" onClick="addStuff();">Click Me</div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
 const addStuff = () => {
   let div = document.getElementById('duplicatediv');
   var x = document.createElement("DIV");                      
var t = document.createTextNode("This is the duplicate.");    
x.appendChild(t);                                           
div.appendChild(x);   
 }

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s7epxLua/

it selects the div with an Id with getElementById, and then appends a div to it.